# how to pass json from php to string constant

Tags: android, json

instead of statically putting the values for 'the_json' how do I pass the json contents of a php to 'the_json'. this is my code

```
try
    {
        String the_json = "{'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}";
        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
        JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
        int length = the_json_array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        String artist_name = another_json_object.optString("name").toString();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_drawer, artist_name,"12"));
      }

    }
```

EDIT: Tried this... nothing happened

```
String url="http//10.0.2.2/jan/android/fave.php";

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();   
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                 String the_json = reader.readLine();
        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
        JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("products");
        int length = the_json_array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        String artist_name = another_json_object.optString("title").toString();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_drawer, artist_name,"12"));
      }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `pass the json contents of a php`. If the php page on your web server is responding with JSON, you can get it with a web request.

Comment: yes, it responds with JSON, how do i do a web request and pass it to 'the_json'?

Comment: have you tried looking for it a bit? Something like "android perform http request" ?

Comment: added a code above, it has http request but nothing shows

Comment: Are you using AsuyncTask in the updated part? because, In latest version of android you have to use HTTPClient in AsyncTask otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant, If your php url gives a json object, U can get that by using httpget method in android

The code is given below.

```
String url="http//"myurl.php";

             HttpGet httpGet = new     HttpGet(url);    

             httpGet.setHeader("name of header", "value of heder"));
              HttpResponse response = null;
             if(mHttpClient != null || !mHttpClient.equals(null) || !mHttpClient.equals("")) 
             {
             response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
             }
             else
             {
             mHttpClient = getClient();
             response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
             }
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
             String the_json = reader.readLine();
```

and continue with your code..

Please ignore if this is not what you meant.

Comment: yes that is what im looking for, but the code gives me errors... mHTTPClient cannot be resolved to a variable, I dont know what to do with that... and should I edit the values of httpGet.setHeader?

Comment: HttpClient mHttpClient = DefaultHttpClient();